# basic turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, logic

I'm trying to create a TM that changes all $a$'s to $b$'s and all $b$'s to $a$'s in a given string and then halts on the first blank space it encounters. What I have is:

$$ \langle q_1,a,b,q_1\rangle \\
\langle q_1,b,R,q_2 \rangle \\
\langle q_2,a,L,q_1 \rangle \\
\langle q_2,b,a,q_2 \rangle \\
$$

I'm new to Turing machines, so I'm wondering if it makes sense to convert $a$'s to $b$'s and then send $b$'s into a different state; is there a sort of temporal sequencing here that will send the $q_1$-manufactured $b$'s (former $a$'s) into $q_2$ as well? If so, how can you get around this problem to construct a suitable machine?

Comment: The moves are missing, there should be: state, read symbol, write symbol, move, new state (order may vary). If your task is to switch all 'a' to 'b' and all 'b' to 'a', you do not need another state, I do not understand why it would be needed (but of course you may use them) and what is the problem. Firstly think how algorithm would work, if it helps try it in terms of your favourite programming language. Then translate it to operations supported by TM.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what Turing machines do. States and tape symbols are completely separate: you can't "send" one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Using your convention that the machine EITHER changes symbol OR moves Left/Right, then this is the machine you are looking for:

```
<q1,a,b,q2>
<q1,b,a,q2>
<q2,a,R,q1>
<q2,b,R,q1>
```

In other words, the machine alternates between the 'switch the letter' state and the 'move right' state.  *[I am adopting the convention that the absence of a transition - say on space - is equivalent to halting; otherwise one needs another transition to cover that]*

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with your notation but this is what i came up with given your problem.

[image: this is what i came up with]

---

Edit: **Explanation**

Given a Truing Mashine is a tuple:

> M = (Q, Σ, Γ, δ, q0, qacc, qrej),

Where:

> - Q is the finite set of states,
> - Σ is the finite input alphabet,
> - Γ ⊇ Σ is the finite tape alphabet (we assume ⊳,⊲ ∈ Γ)
> - δ : (Q − {qacc,qrej}) × (Γ∪ {⊳,⊲}) → Q × (Γ∪ {⊳,⊲}) × {L,R} is the    transition function
> - q0 ∈ Q is the start state (q0 != qacc and q0 != qrej),
> - qacc ∈ Q is the accept state
> - qrej ∈ Q is the reject state (qrej != qacc)

**Interpretation of transition function:**

> δ( q, a) = (q', b, ∆)

**When in state q and reading the symbol a on the tape the machine:**

- Moves to state q'
- Writes the symbol b on initial tape position.
- Moves the tape one position to the direction ∆(L~left,R~Right)

The notations of the transitions in the picture are actually wrong, should be: a,

> b/R -> **a/b,R**
> b, a/R -> **b/a,R**
> ⊲, ⊲/R -> **⊲/⊲,L**
>
> Where ⊲ is the tape symbol for the end of the tape.

And

> Where ⊳ is the tape symbol for the beginning of the tape.

Where `a/b,R` means:

> - Read input symbol a
> - Write b in it's place
> - Move tape right

Where `b/a,R` means:

> - Read input symbol b
> - Write a in it's place
> - Move tape right

Where `⊲/⊲,R` means:

> - Read input symbol ⊲
> - Write ⊲ in it's place
> - Move tape left

Comment: Please add some explanation of what this machine does and how it works. You're answering a question written by somebody whose notation you don't understand -- what makes you think they understand yours?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sorry I assumed it was the _standard_ way of notation.

Comment: And the asker assumed that their way was the standard! There are multiple ways of doing things. Thanks for editing to explain what your notation (which is indeed one of the standard ones) means. I think we can assume that anyone who's reading this question and its answers knows how Turing machines work in general; rather, I meant that you should explain how this particular Turing machine solves the problem it's supposed to solve. (Analogy: if you'd written a Java program, I'd expect you to explain what that program does, not the syntax and semantics of the Java langauge.)